# WPF Button with Image

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to attach an image on a button in WPF, however this code fails.  Seems strange after similar code would work perfectly in Mozilla XUL.

```
<Button Height="49.086" Margin="3.636,12,231.795,0" Name="button2" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Click="button2_Click" 
        Source="Pictures/apple.jpg">Disconnect from Server</Button>
```

Answer (score 265, accepted):

You want to do something like this instead:

```
<Button>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="Pictures/apple.jpg" />
        <TextBlock>Disconnect from Server</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add apple.jpg to project. (Build Action: Resource)

Comment: This is a pretty bad solution as the text and image won't be _grayed out_ when you disable the button.

Comment: @NumLock where is your solution so?

Comment: this won't work if you want to only add a image. I needed to remove the StackPanel and add the image as content of the button to get this working. I didn't test it, but maybe this is the way to go if one wants an image and the text.

Comment: If you have the image added to your project you can drag from it the solution explorer to the xaml editor and it will put in the text of the full path to the image.

Comment: Working good. But you have to adjust Button Height, Image height and alignment, also you may need button Background property to set Transparent.

Answer (score 16):

Another way to Stretch image to full button. Can try the below code.

```
<Grid.Resources>
  <ImageBrush x:Key="AddButtonImageBrush" ImageSource="/Demoapp;component/Resources/AddButton.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</Grid.Resources>

<Button Content="Load Inventory 1" Background="{StaticResource AddButtonImageBrush}"/>
```

Referred from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106888/image-fill-the-space-on-the-button-in-wpf)

Also it might helps other. I posted the same with [MouseOver Option here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26063410/2466650).

Answer (score 11):

Most simple approach would be using the Image tag.

```
<Button Name="btn" Width="26" Height="26" Click="btnClick"> 
   <Image Source="Resource/btn-icon.png"/>
</Button>
```

Suppose your image file is added in Resource folder

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 5):

```
<Button x:Name="myBtn_DetailsTab_Save" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="835,544,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="143" Height="53" BorderBrush="#FF0F6287" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontFamily="B Titr" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="2" Click="myBtn_DetailsTab_Save_Click">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FF1FB3F5" Cursor="Hand" >
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Source="image/bg/Save.png" Height="36" Width="124" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="84" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-31,-58,0" Text="ثبت مشتری" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: You should explain your answer, sometimes only code is not enough to understand the content

Comment: if use this button then you have this error"a value of type 'datagridtextcolumn' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type observablecollection" or Similar error you shoud add style  …>                   <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="headerStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>

Comment: It was useful and solved my problem, thanks. and don't forget to change 'ثبت مشتری' to 'submit' for other than Persian ones! :D

Answer (score 4):

This should do the job, no?

```
<Button Content="Test">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="folder/file.PNG"/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom control that inherits from the Button class. This code will be more reusable, please look at the following blog post for more details: [WPF - create custom button with image (ImageButton)](https://kmatyaszek.github.io/2020/04/16/wpf-image-button.html)

Using this control:

```
<local:ImageButton Width="200" Height="50" Content="Click Me!"
    ImageSource="ok.png" ImageLocation="Left" ImageWidth="20" ImageHeight="25" />
```

ImageButton.cs file:

```
public class ImageButton : Button
{
   static ImageButton()
   {
       DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ImageButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ImageButton)));
   }

   public ImageButton()
   {
       this.SetCurrentValue(ImageButton.ImageLocationProperty, WpfImageButton.ImageLocation.Left);
   }

   public int ImageWidth
   {
       get { return (int)GetValue(ImageWidthProperty); }
       set { SetValue(ImageWidthProperty, value); }
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageWidthProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ImageWidth", typeof(int), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(30));

   public int ImageHeight
   {
       get { return (int)GetValue(ImageHeightProperty); }
       set { SetValue(ImageHeightProperty, value); }
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageHeightProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ImageHeight", typeof(int), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(30));

   public ImageLocation? ImageLocation
   {
       get { return (ImageLocation)GetValue(ImageLocationProperty); }
       set { SetValue(ImageLocationProperty, value); }
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageLocationProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ImageLocation", typeof(ImageLocation?), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(null, PropertyChangedCallback));

   private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       var imageButton = (ImageButton)d;
       var newLocation = (ImageLocation?) e.NewValue ?? WpfImageButton.ImageLocation.Left;

       switch (newLocation)
       {
           case WpfImageButton.ImageLocation.Left:
               imageButton.SetCurrentValue(ImageButton.RowIndexProperty, 1);
               imageButton.SetCurrentValue(ImageButton.ColumnIndexProperty, 0);
               break;
           case WpfImageButton.ImageLocation.Top:
               imageButton.SetCurrentValue(ImageButton.RowIndexProperty, 0);
               imageButton.SetCurrentValue(ImageButton.ColumnIndexProperty, 1);
               break;
           case WpfImageButton.ImageLocation.Right:
               imageButton.SetCurrentValue(ImageButton.RowIndexProperty, 1);
               imageButton.SetCurrentValue(ImageButton.ColumnIndexProperty, 2);
               break;
           case WpfImageButton.ImageLocation.Bottom:
               imageButton.SetCurrentValue(ImageButton.RowIndexProperty, 2);
               imageButton.SetCurrentValue(ImageButton.ColumnIndexProperty, 1);
               break;
           case WpfImageButton.ImageLocation.Center:
               imageButton.SetCurrentValue(ImageButton.RowIndexProperty, 1);
               imageButton.SetCurrentValue(ImageButton.ColumnIndexProperty, 1);
               break;
           default:
               throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
       }
   }

   public ImageSource ImageSource
   {
       get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
       set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

   public int RowIndex
   {
       get { return (int)GetValue(RowIndexProperty); }
       set { SetValue(RowIndexProperty, value); }
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty RowIndexProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("RowIndex", typeof(int), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(0));

   public int ColumnIndex
   {
       get { return (int)GetValue(ColumnIndexProperty); }
       set { SetValue(ColumnIndexProperty, value); }
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnIndexProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnIndex", typeof(int), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(0));
}

public enum ImageLocation
{
   Left,
   Top,
   Right,
   Bottom,
   Center
}
```

Generic.xaml file:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfImageButton">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:ImageButton}}"
                               Width="{Binding ImageWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:ImageButton}}"
                               Height="{Binding ImageHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:ImageButton}}"
                               Grid.Row="{Binding RowIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:ImageButton}}"
                               Grid.Column="{Binding ColumnIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:ImageButton}}"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Image>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its late but here is my solution:

```
<Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
   Name="btnLogout" Click="btnLogout_Click">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <fa5:ImageAwesome Icon="Solid_ShareSquare" Margin="5"
      Width="20" Height="20"
      Foreground="Maroon"/>
    <TextBlock FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"
               Margin="5">Log Out</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

It looks like this

[image]

Comment: Missing a closing </Button>