# Image is displayed in large size and cropped even if size declared is same as source

Tags: wpf, image

I have a png image with size 30x30. Then i created an image inside a button using my 30x30 image:

```
<Button>
  <Image x:Name="Sample" Source="sample.png" Stretch="None" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
         Width="30" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Button>
```

But still the image is displayed big and cropped in the Image control. Why does this happen even they have the same size?

Comment: Maybe the two images have different [DPI resolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch)?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7987448/7483664).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image in `sample.png` might have different DPI than 96, which WPF uses as the size of its [device independent units](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-graphics-rendering-overview#visual-rendering-behavior).

Just don't set `Stretch="None"` on the Image element in order to get it scaled correctly. The default value of Stretch is `Uniform`.

```
<Image Source="sample.png" Width="30" Height="30"/>
```

---

You can check the difference between the native size and the (unstretched) rendered size of an image if you load it into a BitmapImage and compare its `Width` and `Height` with its `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight`.