# Wpf Button with image - using Style/Template

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to have an image button for my Wpf application. At first i was happy with this answer i've found ([WPF Button with Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697383/wpf-button-with-image)).

However, now i want to make a **style/template** out of it, so i don't need to write the same thing over and over again.

The closest i could get was this image:

[Image showing the three buttons i got so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBnJn.png)

**The problem is**: I've lost the background (seems like there's nothing!). I already tried to get the background back with a Rectangle, but then, **the button has no animations** - there's no mouse over or click different colors. Seems like by using a template i erased it all...

That's not what i wanted to. **I wanted to simply set a template and have all the default colors/animations**.

This is my XAML so far:

```
<Style x:Key="btnSave" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/Resources/save.png"></Image>

                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What i wanted was to simply use it as:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource btnSave}">Save File</Button>
```

And have a button with an image and default colors/animations.

Is there a simple way to do this? I don't want to mess with Triggers so far, all the links i've found about this try to teach how to make a full custom button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy: Use a `ContentTemplate`, which templatizes just the content area of the `Button`, not the whole thing. `Button` supports that because it inherits from `ContentControl`. Pretty much anything with a `Content` property in WPF will support exactly the same thing.

The `DataTemplate` in there has the control's `Content` property for its `DataContext`, so you bind the `Content` simply with `{Binding}`. And I took the liberty of giving the image a bit of a right margin, so it doesn't rub up against the regular button content.

```
<Style x:Key="btnSave" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Source="/Resources/save.png"
                        Margin="0,0,8,0"
                        />

                    <ContentControl
                        Content="{Binding}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the default `Button` template and only somewhat decorate it's content, your best bet is to facilitate the `Button.ContentTemplate` property. Since it's a dependency property it can be styled/bound/etc. Here's how it could look in your case:

```
<Style x:Key="btnSave" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/Resources/save.png"></Image>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The only differences are that you use a `DataTemplate` instead of `ControlTemplate` and you need to bind the `ContentPresenter.Content` property inside the template. Note that in this case we're templating the object being the value of `Button.Content`, hence the binding has no path specified.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. I wonder why i never found about ContentTemplate before, it seems so obvious. Can i ask you how you know about that? I am new to WPF and would like to research more. -- edt: i will be accepting ed's answer because you both answered equally right, but he did so in 3 minutes earlier... i'm kinda sorry i can't accept nor upvote them both.

Comment: @diego.dona I usually learn something when I am faced with a problem - be it in work or when I find a question on SO I don't know the answer to (and would like to). Then I start off with MSDN documentation, and then search SO for similar problems. If that fails, then I fall back to Google and/or simple Trial and Error method of playing around with code.