# WPF - Trying to create image in button but it is displayed smaller when app is running than in the VS2019 IDE

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a button bar with images. My Xaml is as follows:

```
<Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <StackPanel x:Name="ButtonsPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
        <Button x:Name="NewButton" Margin="3" Command="ApplicationCommands.New" ToolTip="New project" BorderThickness="0">
            <Image Source="/Resources/NewFile_16x.png"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="OpenProjectButton" Margin="3" Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" ToolTip="Open project" BorderThickness="0">
            <Image Source="/Resources/OpenFile_16x.png"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="SaveProjectButton" Margin="3" Command="ApplicationCommands.Save" ToolTip="Save project" BorderThickness="0">
            <Image Source="/Resources/Save_16x.png"/>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

It all looks fine in the IDE (VS2019 Community) but when I run the app, the images are really small. If I've tried adding Height and Width properties to the Button and/or the Image tag, but all that does display a gray square of the correct dimensions but with no image. I added Stretch="Fill" in the image tag, but it didn't help. I even tried images of different sizes to see if that was the problem, but nothing seems to help.

Any advice would be appreciated.

[Edit]

I was wrong about what was being displayed with the small images. As it happens, it's the same gray squares, just smaller. So it's not a sizing problem per se, but a rendering one ... ?

If it helps any, here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to set `Stretch="Fill"` for images? Or place in inside a stack panel, like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697383/wpf-button-with-image)?

Comment: Try to use `Grid` instead of `StackPanel`. Or set `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` as you wish.

Comment: You can adjust `MinWidth` and` MinHeight` in `xaml` at runtime. So it doesn't matter what it looks like in the IDE.

Comment: Can you post screen shots so we can see what you are seeing?